# Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1 - PageContentAssembler

Tags: content-delivery, dd4t, broker, api

Observing some strange behaviour in our code thats is pulling back published page content from broker.

This is DD4T (except we use WCFs a DD4T providers to get stuff out of broker) - when we query for "/index.html", the DD4T XML is returned as expected.

But when we query for "/resource.resx" or "/web.sitemap" - nothing is returned. Both pages are definitely in the broker (I can see both in PAGE and PAGE_CONTENT tables).

Through our debug code, I can even see the initial Query successfully find the TCMs for both pages, (meaning both where successfully found in the PAGE table by their URL). The problem seems to be with the PageContentAssembler.GetContent(string TCM) which is supposed to return rendered content.

Event though its given a correct TCM, it returns an empty string for both those pages - its as though it doesn't like the RESX or SITEMAP XML structure?

Anyone seen this before - does PageContentAssembler.GetContent do some post processing after its retrieved content?

**UPDATE**

So according to the docs PageContentAssembler will try and run any code inside published content - could this be whats happening and the result of "running" the RESX XML is null?

The Target Language is set to "None" for my Publication Target - is PageContentAssembler's behaviour influenced by other config settings?

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

OK, as usual the answer was far more straight-forward than I'd originally imagined!

cd_storage_conf.xml on the server running Tridion CD API was not updated to reflect that for this specific publication, the RESX and SITEMAP files are published to the dB.

The deployer's cd_storage_conf.xml was right, hence why I could see content in broker.
It wasn't being retrieved because on the API was configured to look in the file system.

Doh!